# Python img.zoom() allows only integer

Tags: python, tkinter, zooming, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to zoom picture in python but I am able to get only zoom 2x 3x 4x... I am unable to get zoom 1.5x which I need.

```
    tag1 = tk.PhotoImage(file='assets/tag1.jpg')
    tag1 = tag1.zoom(2)
```

When I try 1.5 I get an error that the argument can be only integer.
I will be thankful for any help or trick on how to overcome this.

Comment: What is `tag1`? Please read [ask].

Comment: @Chris Thank Chris i edited my question. Hopefully is now clear.

Comment: you can keep image as `pillow` image and rescale it with `pillow` and replace in `PhotoImage` or on `Canvas`. Somewhere on Stackoveflow should be this show in question like `"how to resize background image when tkinter window changes size"`

Comment: It seems you aready found solution. I found mentioned example on my github: [resize-image-in-background](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/tkinter/resize-image-in-background/main-one-image.py)

Comment: Yes, the `zoom` method is documented to only take integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well thanks for help in comments. At the end of the day its solved.

```
    from PIL import Image
    from PIL import ImageTk

    tag1 = Image.open('assets/tag1.jpg')
    tag1 = tag1.resize((tagWidth,tagHeight), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    tag1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(tag1)
```